# Rearranging Conditionally Convergent Sums

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Consider a series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\alpha_n$ which converges, but does not absolutely converge. Of course, there is some bijection $\phi:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ such that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\alpha_{\phi_n}\neq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\alpha_n.$$ But there also exist bijections which do not affect the value of a series. Example:
$\phi_n=qm+\sigma_r$, where $n=qm+r$, $r\in\mathbb{Z}_m,$ and $\sigma\in S_m.$ Notice that $$\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}\alpha_{qm+\tau_r}\rightarrow0$$ as $q\rightarrow\infty$ for any $\tau\in S_m,$ so the two sums will approach each other. My guess for a conjecture would be: Iff $|\phi_n-n|$ is bounded from above, then for any sequence $(\alpha_n)$ tending towards 0, $$|\sum_{n=1}^N(\alpha_{\phi_n}-\alpha_n)|$$ also tends towards 0. I was able to prove the forward direction, and with enough time, I think I could prove the backward direction. However, I don't want to bark up the wrong tree. Does anyone know of a similar or possibly inconsistent result?

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/q/213046/116247